# Problem Loading Xml File asp.net mvc

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

Heres my code:

```
XElement navegacion;
    public Navegacion()
    {
        this.navegacion = XElement.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/navegacion.xml"));
    }
```

It works just fine when I go to:

http://localhost/Default.aspx

an when I go to

http://localhost/Users

But it cant open the file when I go to

http://localhost/Users/Index

or

http://localhost/Users/Index/1

or any other id for that matter.

Navegacion class is a Model.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another slash before the path to make it relative to the root, and not the current folder. That is why it works on `Default.aspx`, but not `/Home` etc, as that makes `MapPath` return `/Home/App_Data/navegacion.xml`.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/navegacion.xml")
```